# splitting words in string based on '\n'

Tags: python, string, split

guys I have a string that I am trying to make an ngram of, but I have a problem, when I do `ngram = ngrams(raw_text.split(" "), n=1`
the output is

```
[('come',), ('here,',), ('girl\noh,',), ('you',)....]
```

The problem is that in my string the words are arranged like:

```
come here, girl\noh, you want...
```

which means that my ngram is much bigger than it needs to be
so what would I do to get a string like

```
come here , girl \n oh , you ...
```

so that my ngram is an order smaller 
thanks guys 
I hope youre all having a good day

EDIT i am now aware that Im using a delimiter and have changed that... so \n problem gone, but can I split the words within a string that have punctuation in them?

Comment: You are explicitly choosing to split only on `' '`. Do `raw_text.split()` instead.

Comment: What is `raw_text`? Does it come from a file?

Comment: thanks man that is an improvement, but I was thinking I could probably cut the ngram in half if i couls split the words within the string that had punctuation in it

Comment: yeah man, but its just lines in a txt file

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ? Can you provide an explicit input / desired output example?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I split the words within a string that have punctuation in them?

Your final result is still not clear: do you want to include punctuation or just discard it entirely? Assuming that you don't need the punctuation, this is trivial using `re.split()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'\W+', "Hello, this'll split by\n \nwhitespace and also puncutation!")
['Hello', 'this', 'll', 'split', 'by', 'whitespace', 'and', 'also', 'puncutation', '']
```

If you want to split in a smarter way, this can quickly become complicated. I recommend using the `nltk` toolkit, which provides among other options `nltk.word_tokenize`:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.word_tokenize("Hello, this'll split by\n \nwhitespace and also puncutation!")
['Hello', ',', 'this', "'ll", 'split', 'by', 'whitespace', 'and', 'also', 'puncutation', '!']
```